# Where can i change Rating for Ready For Sale app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

My app is already live on the store, Now I have submitted new version of it on the store but Apple has rejected new version with the reason :

> Your app's rating must reflect a "Frequent/Intense" setting for Mature/Suggestive Themes in App Store Connect.

I have already changed `Rating` in new version :

[image]

But every time `Apple` rejects app with this reason. So I am thinking that I must have to change `Rating` for live version, but how can I change this ?

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: You can only change an app's rating when submitting a new version.

Comment: That I know. And I have tried, but no luck.

Comment: it is still showing the previous rating?

Comment: We can not change Ratings for the live version.

Comment: @shivi_shub Yes.